# what does odbc Action keyword do?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i just came across a code, which is more like

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE Columname=filtercriteria AND action='update'
```

what does action mention in the above code? How can we implement it? can we assign values to it? if so, how?
I tried searching in the net, but wasnt able to find any answer. :(

Comment: Does this code works? I mean "WHERE Columname=filtercriteria" - what is filtercriteria?

Comment: well it can mean like this
     Select * from Products where ProductId=2
where tablename is Products, Columnname is ProductId and filtercriteria is 2

Comment: am more interested in the keyword action and its implementation though. Voo have u worked on this??

Comment: Is action not just another column name in that table?

Comment: no....apparently its a ODBC keyword....and am wondering what does it do?? and how to implement and initialize it

Answer (score 0):

Action - is the name of the column and 'update' is a value, which is used to filter the SELECT result statement.
Also it can be the reserved keyword ODBC, but i don't think it is used in your case

Answer (score 0):

Action is a field/column name, that is why you can't find a reference for it. 'action' is being used here to filter your result set.

To add values to your table `TableName` using the two columns you reference you would do

```
INSERT INTO TableName 
VALUES ('SomeCriteria', 'SomeAction'); 
GO
```

Note, that this is assuming these columns are of 'CHAR'-type.

I hope this helps.